# Question about eigenvalue problem range space

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

A theorem from Axler's Linear Algebra Done Right says that if  is a linear operator on a complex finite dimensional vector space , then there exists a basis  for  such that the matrix of  with respect to the basis  is upper triangular.

In the proof, he defines U=range(T-I) (as we have proved atleast one eigenvalue must exist)and says that this is invariant under T.

First I want understand what the range space is here. Suppose we are in 2D and I choose some basis consisting on an eigenvector($e_v$) and another free vector(v): ( $e_v$, v) Now this v can be anything not necessarily an eigenvector. So there are many possibilities. Are all contained in U? U can have dimension 1 but all these possibilities are not linearly independent so what exactly is U? Is it a set of all vectors not in the span of $e_v$? Does this not conflict with U having dimension 1?

He then proves this by saying if u belongs to U then Tu=(T-I)u + Tu and both (T-I)u and Tu belong to U. But if I had chosen a non-eigenvalue for my basis, then Tu does not scale it so it is mapped to some other span. Therefore I'm guessing U is a set.

Any other comments about (T-I)v would be appreciated. How to think of it in the context of our original T? (I know the null space is the eigenvector)

Answer (score 0):

$T-\lambda I$ is a linear map as it is the sum of two linear map(if you think of $\lambda I$ as the linear map that sends a vector $v$ to $\lambda v$). The image of a linear map is always a subspace. And hence $U:=range(T-\lambda I)$ is indeed a subspace of $V$.

The proof says $U$ is invariant under $T$. He did not consider eigenvector basis at all, He says pick $u\in U$, then $T(u)=T(u)-\lambda u+\lambda u=(T-\lambda I)(u)+\lambda u$. And from there, he deduced $T(u)$ is in $U$ as both $(t-\lambda I)(u)$ and $\lambda u$ is in $U$.

Now,since $T-\lambda I$ is not surjective, $dim(U)<dim(V)$.So we can apply induction on $U$ to get a basis $B_U$ for $U$ in which $T$ restricted to $U$ is upper triangular(Here we used the fact that $U$ is invariant under $T$ as otherwise we wouldn't be able to apply the induction hypothesis). Then when we complete $B_U$ to a basis $B$ for $V$, we have that $T$ with respect to the basis $B$ is upper triangular where he proved that result using the conditions for a linear map to be upper triangular.

So I'm not sure what is $img(T-\lambda I)$.

Comment: You didnt answer my question. If a space has dim 2, then :=(−) for a  must have dim 1 as the null space is the eigenvector space. However U may contain more than one linearly independant vectors, as if the eigenvector was (1,1) then vectors (1,2) and (1,3) must be in U and they are independant, so doesent the dim of U now equal 2 ?

Comment: Ah, so if I understand correctly, let's say $V$ has dimension $2$ and we could have $U$ have dimension $2$ as well? Is that was the question, then notice that $U$ could not have dimension 2 as $T-\lambda I$ is not surjective.The null space of $T-\lambda I$ is not $U$, $U$ is the image of $T-\lambda I$ i.e the column space.

Comment: Yes, thats what I said in 2D space ':=(−) for a  must have dim 1 as the null space is the eigenvector space'. In the comment above I am saying suppose the eigenvector related to this  is span(1,1). So everything except span(1,1) must be in U. Therefore span(1,2) and span(1,3) must be in U. But notice that span(1,2) and span(1,3)  are linearly independant. This contradicts the statement that U is dim 1 as we have show two linearly independant vectors. Please let me know if any step is unclear.

Comment: good point, I don't understand either, Hopefully, someone will answer:) But by your argument, since there are infinitely many lines through the origin, and each of them is the span of some unit vector, each of those vectors are pairwise linearly independent, so then $R$ would be infinite dimensional. So the argument is wrong. The problem is that the image of $T-\lambda I$ is not whatever that is not in null of $T-\lambda I$.

Comment: Example, T(x,y)=(x,0) has null space the y-axis but image is the x-axis and not whatever that is not in the null space. And I'm charging $5 for my answer as pure mathematician usually can't find jobs except teaching at college :).

Comment: Your username is LOL. Are you Indian? That's Marathi right or a coincidence?